Does a constant symbol with a free variable imply a contradiction in FOL?
When listening to this talk, I came across an interesting claim (at 12:30) which I wanted to verify:

[...] We have defined a constant (called and) which takes no arguments and unfolds to something containing variables $a$ and $b$, which can be whatever we like. It is an interesting exercise to show that a constant with such properties is inconsistent.

My interpretation of this claim in FOL is the following: We have a language of classical FOL (with identity!) with the signature $\{ T(x) \}$. For all terms $t$ and $k$, $T(t)$ and $T(k)$ are taken to be meta-logically equal, as if they were the same string.
Viewing $T(x)$ as a unary function from the domain onto itself, it is derivable that:

$T(x)$ is a constant function, i.e., $\forall x \forall y.T(x) = T(y)$ (obvious, from the properties of constant symbols),
$T(x)$ has a fixed point, i.e., $\exists y.y = T(y)$,
the domain has only one element, i.e., $\forall x\forall y.x = y$ (this requires LEM).

However, I failed to derive a contradiction. I am interested in whether my interpretation of the exercise was even roughly correct in the first place, and if so, what is the solution. If not, I am interested in the correct interpretation of the exercise.

IMO it means simply that if we do not specify that the function "and" has two argument places, what we get from the program is the def of a "constant": $\lnot ( a \to \lnot b)$ that can have sometimes value T and sometimes F, meaning that is not constant.

I think the gist of what Mario is saying is that if you have a symbol "$\mathrm{and}$" such that $\forall a b. (\mathrm{and} = a \land b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are universally quantified at the meta level, you can prove that $\top = \top \land \top = \mathrm{and} = \bot \land \bot = \bot$ and get a contradiction.

It means simply that if we do not specify that the function "and" has two argument places, what we get from the program is the definition of a sort of constant: $¬(a → ¬b)$ that can have sometimes value $\top$ (True) and sometimes $\bot$ (False), and this amounts to saying that it is not a constant at all.
